# Finding position of a character related to the position of another character in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring, nsrange

say I have a txt file with data as follows;

```
12345,123,98765,JOHN,RL,s/w
12345,123,98765,SAM,RL,s/w 
12345,123,98765,MIC,RL,s/w
12345,123,98765,MIC,RL,s/w
12345,123,98765,MIC,RL,s/w
12345,123,98765,MIC,RL,s/w
12345,123,98765,MIC,RL,s/w
12345,123,98765,AMI,RL,s/w
12345,123,98765,THIMOTHY,RL,s/w
```

It is bundled within my app and I am reading the data to a nsstring. And I am passing a search term, say 'MIC'. When I pass this search term, I want to get the lines which having the search term and delete all other lines from the string.

I have tried following code:

```
NSString *searchTerm = @"MIC";
    NSRange rangess = [dataToBeParsed rangeOfString:searchTerm];

    NSRange range = [dataToBeParsed rangeOfString:@"" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:rangess];
    NSLog(@"range.location: %lu", range.location);
    NSString *substring = [dataToBeParsed substringFromIndex:range.location+1];
    NSLog(@"substring: \n%@'", substring);
```

I am able to find the location of search term and clear the string content till search location. But I want to get the complete line.

Note: In my original doc, the lines which having a search term will be listed continuously as in the doc.

Please help.

Comment: Holding it in a string is not correct.  You want an array of an array of strings.

Comment: You may use a regular expression: `^(.*(?:MIC).*)$`. Just replace `MIC` with whatever you want to look for. Evaluating this expression will give you full lines.

Comment: As @trojanfoe said, it should be better to use NSArray of NSArray, especially when it seems to be CSV "with comma as separator".

Comment: Yes, I understand what you meant. But my original doc will be having more than 2 lack entries. So loading into array using componentsSeperatedByString:@"\n" was taking time.

Comment: @akashivskyy tried that as well, but we are targeting the app for iPod touch 4th gen device. So its taking more time. :(

Comment: @Larme yes it is a csv file reading operation and each item is comma separated.

Comment: Why you want to do heavy operations on device, If you think handling 2 lakh rows takes more time then you should do this on server side.

Comment: @Mr.T Actually this should be done from our client. We have suggested this but now they are not in a position to do this. That is why we are trying to follow this approach and get better performance.

Comment: @Mithun: Does this file change, or is it part of you app bundle?  If it does *not* change, you can take the time to parse it into an array of lines just once, and then archive and load the array on subsequent runs.

Comment: @Avi We have to download the csv file every day morning. And each day there will be some modifications. And we have tried to load the data into Array, Coredata etc. But the time taken was too high to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that two things cause the greatest costs:

- searching the whole string again and again
- creation of instances for partial string.

However, you can get rid of both by using ranges on the whole string instead of creating substrings:

```
NSUInteger length = [source length];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange( 0, length );
NSRange hitRange = NSMakeRange( 0, 0 );

// Iterate over the string unless you do not find any hit
while( (hitRange = [source rangeOfString:@"Mic" options:0 range:searchRange]).length != 0)
{
   // hitRange contains the range we found "Mic". We have to enlarge it on both sides to \n
   NSRange lineRange = [source rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSBackwardSearch range:NSMakeRange( 0, hitRange.location ); // Maybe it is an optimization to cut the range ahead of the hit to the last hit. But since it is a backward search, I do not think that this has any effect.

   // We can enlarge the range to the prev \n:
   hitRange.length = hitRange.range + hitRange.location - lineRange.location +1;

   // Go the the next \n
   lineRange = [source rangeOfString:@"\n" options:0 range:NSMakeRange( hitRange.location+hitRange.length, length-hitRange.location+hitRange.length)];

   hitRange.length = lineRange.location-hitRange.location;

   // Do something with the line
   …

   // Move forward
   searchRange.location = hitRange.location+hitRange.length;
   searchRange.length = length-searchRange.location;
}
```

Typed in Safari, just to show the approach. Definetly there are +1/-1 errors in it and some optimizations to reduce the search for single chars.

Obviously this works only, if there are \n at the end and beginning. Add \n if not so.

I really do not know, whether this is faster or not. However, it is worth a try.

As an addition you can make a method in a category of `NSString` out of it taking a block that takes the range. This would make it more generic.

**Modified Code:**

```
NSUInteger length = [dataToBeParsedFirst length];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange( 0, length );
NSRange hitRange = NSMakeRange( 0, 0 );
NSMutableArray *linesArr =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Iterate over the string unless you do not find any hit
while( (hitRange = [dataToBeParsedFirst rangeOfString:ItemID options:0 range:searchRange]).length != 0)
{
    NSRange lineRange = [dataToBeParsedFirst rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange( 0, hitRange.location )];

    NSRange lineEndRange = [dataToBeParsedFirst rangeOfString:@"\n" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(hitRange.location, 500)];

    NSRange dataRange = NSMakeRange(lineRange.location + lineRange.length, lineEndRange.location - lineRange.location + lineRange.length - 1);

    [linesArr addObject:[[dataToBeParsedFirst substringWithRange:dataRange] substringToIndex:dataRange.length - 1]];

    // Move forward
    searchRange.location = lineEndRange.location+lineEndRange.length;
    searchRange.length = length-searchRange.location;
}

NSString *dataToBeParsed = [[linesArr componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much @amin. This what I was trying to do. I have made few modifications to the code and it worked as I expected!! :) Earlier it was taking around 15 seconds to complete the search operation. Now it is taking just 8 seconds!!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string        = stringDataToBeParsed;
NSArray *components     = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableArray *array   = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSString *string in components)
{
    if ([string containsString:searchTerm])
    {
        [array addObject:string];
    }
}

NSString *stringWithSearchLinesOnly = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

If the above isn't fast enough, then in Objective-c you can't really get faster than this:

```
NSString *string             = stringDataToBeParsed;
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];

[string enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull line, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)
{
    if ([line containsString:searchTerm])
    {
        [mutableArray addObject:line];
    }
}];

NSString *stringWithSearchLinesOnly = [mutableArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this method, but the problem is, as the csv file has more than 2 lack rows, to looping through all these rows is taking more time.

Comment: This is how we did finally.Still it was taking around 15 seconds to complete the operation.

Comment: Yes you won't get it much faster in Objective-C. The only unnecessary/inefficient  operation in the code above is adding back in the end of line terminator. enumerateLinesUsingBlock is very efficient because it is operating on your existing object and does not need to create a new one. Adding to a mutable array can be made quite a lot faster if you specify a size on creation, but you don't know the size in advance. Still if you already know there will be at least x lines - it might marginally improve performance if you specify [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:x];

Comment: What I meant is I had tried the method already. But I was asking is, say if I have a string and I am passing a search term. I could find the location of the search term. But I wont get that complete line. So I was trying to get the very last "\n" position before the searched term location and get the entire line. That is what I asked in my question. Any idea?

Comment: You really should find out why the posted solution is so slow for you.  It shouldn't be.  String scanning to find line terminators is far more expensive.

Comment: What is "2 lack"?  That's slang I am not familiar with.

Comment: Yes, to iterate arbitrary positions in unicode UTF-16 string and iteratively determine a range from that point until e.g. a line end, is inefficient because the range determination is having to check for surrogate pairs (and doesn't make assumptions). Indeed also reverse enumeration of string ranges as you are doing above is also perhaps causing a lot more work to be done than perhaps you think Mithun. see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008025

Comment: 2 lack = 200,000 0r 0.2 million @Avi :)

Comment: @TheBasicMind "enumerateLinesUsingBlock is very efficient because it is operating on your existing object and does not need to create a new one. " Where does the `line` object come from?

Comment: In the first code sample I gave, the entire string is split into an array with new string objects before starting to iterate over the string - which is expensive. The second code sample is more efficient because Apple optimise their code and line is a class cluster version of NSString where the reference is to a fragment of the existing allocated string - which is highly efficient. You can confirm this by checking in the debugger - line is a 'taggedPointerString" (as an added bonus, tagged pointers are super efficient on 64 bit devices) !

Comment: BTW, it's worth looking up tagged pointers - they are fascinating. At a guess Apple are storing the offset and length of the fragment in the original string in the pointer itself which will avoid the need for looking up these values from the heap. You really aren't going to get more efficient than this.